# Reasons why Cloud SQL would crash approximately every 24 hours

Tags: google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-platform

I'm consistently seeing less than 24 hours uptime on my cloud SQL instance, despite having it set to always on.

It looks like the instance is crashing as I keep losing new users added (and the mysql users table is in myisam so can't recover from a crash as my indoor data tables can).

Is there a problem with Cloud SQL causing this or is it likely to be something with my configuration?

Comment: Can you try issuing a `FLUSH TABLES` after updating the MyISAM tables?

If you  can contact us at `cloud-sql@google.com` with the instance name we can also tell you if the instance is actually crashing or not.

Comment: Just an update I've been in touch with Razvan through cloud-sql_google.com and the server was running out of memory because of too many connections. Looking at my application though the load wasn't high at that point. It turns out that at a certain point all connections were getting stuck in the "Query End" state causing active connections to spike and the server to crash.

Looking around there's suggestions with mySQL that this could be an issue with log files and disk space so I've disabled the binary log to see if this helps. Hoping Google will look into this for me as well

Answer (score 0):

InnoDB is the Google recommended database engine for Cloud SQL.

If MyISAM is a requirement for you, I´d use MySQL on a Google Compute Engine.

Check:

https://cloud.google.com/sql/faq#innodb

and

https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/launch-checklist

Comment: The Mysql user table is MyISAM, there's no avoiding it.